# JavaFX & MariaDB: Many errors with my simple app

Tags: java, maven, javafx, mariadb

Im making a project for my studies and I cannot figure out what is wrong. For simplicity I made the simplest app possible.
FYI:

- Im using Intellij
- added the Jdbc driver manually, i also added it in maven.
- I can connect using the database with the same information on a non javafx app.

Thank you in advance

```
package com.example.one_fx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

HelloController:

```
package com.example.one_fx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.sql.*;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;


    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");

        Connection connection = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306";
        String user = "root";
        String pwd = "";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            welcomeText.setText("preparing sql");


            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE wow2");
            welcomeText.setText("DB created");




            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Connection Success!");

    }
```

hello-view.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="316.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.one_fx.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText" />
    <Button onAction="#onHelloButtonClick" text="Hello!" />
</VBox>
```

the error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=64556:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\16\javafx-controls-16.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\16\javafx-graphics-16.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\16\javafx-base-16.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\16\javafx-fxml-16.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\mariadb\jdbc\mariadb-java-client\2.7.3\mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\Desktop\Connector driver java\mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar" -p C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\16\javafx-controls-16-win.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\16\javafx-fxml-16-win.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\16\javafx-graphics-16-win.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\16\javafx-base-16-win.jar;C:\Users\VelazquezSilwanySiha\IdeaProjects\one_fx\target\classes -m com.example.one_fx/com.example.one_fx.HelloApplication
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1859)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialException
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:632)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.example.one_fx/com.example.one_fx.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick(HelloController.java:23)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: Looks like you are not adding the `java.sql` module when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with this issue. I found the way to fix this issue. For maven dependency in pom.xml I use 2.4.4 version and try to query something from db  to show with JavaFx I got no error. Or try add connector mariadb version 2.4.4 jar file manually instead(should work too).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```